# How can I make a rectangle change to a circle smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to make an animation in javascript using p5.js library. I want to make a square change its shape transforming into a circle.

I tried drawing a circle behind the square and change the size of the shapes but thats not the effect I'm looking for.

I need to achieve somthing like this, the spin is not important.
[image: a busy cat]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://p5js.org/examples/motion-morph.html) what are you searching for?

Comment: A good video about circle morphing can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvgcNOX8JGQ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should get you going:

```js
var sideLength = 100;
var increment = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  fill(0);
}

function draw() {
  if(increment <= sideLength/2){
    clear();
    increment++;
  }
  rect(10, 10, sideLength, sideLength, increment);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

The key part being the use of the [rect() function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect) where a values for the radius of a rounded corner can be specified.